# Serving Static Content from a Cookieless Domain - using subdomain and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies, static-content

I can have many images per page (e.g. 70) and want to serve them without the overhead of cookies.

I would prefer to set up a subdomain and add a CNAME record (as opposed to having to use a separate domain). Currently, I have a CNAME record for my donmain: www.example.com ==> example.com and I want to keep the functionality of resolving example.com to www.example.com.

I've discovered that when I access my site using www.example.com it uses different cookies from when I use example.com. Could I use .htaccess to redirect all example.com requests to www.example.com requests and solve the problem this way? Would all cookies then default to www.example.com when set?

**UPDATE**
Then I would create the CNAME record static.example.com and point it to www.example.com. I would then point all my image requests to static.example.com. Would they be cookieless?

Comment: Yes, but where does the cookieless image subdomain come in?

Comment: @trex005 - Thanks. What I forgot to say is that I would like to create the CNAME record static.example.com and point it to www.example.com. I would then point all my image requests to static.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's what is needed and good for SEO too. Multiple url for same content is not a good thing. You need to make changes in htaccess file written below.

`RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and report back how it goes.

Comment: So after a long night, it works. I no longer have any cookie data in the request header for file requests served from my cookieless static sub-domain.  Thanks for the .htaccess code.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but it's not immediately guaranteed that static.example.com will be cookieless. You'll need to explicitly set all your cookies for www.example.com so that they won't be shared among subdomains. A separate domain is much easier to deal with in this regard.

Comment: Thank you. Fortunately, all my cookie code is relatively centralized - so explicitly setting the domain shouldn't be too painful. I don't have a spare domain lying around, so I am motivated to make it work.

Comment: Cool beans. Just wanted you to be aware of the additional work involved. Good luck!

Comment: I'm still not positive that explicitly setting the domain is needed. The docs say that cookies will default the domain to the current domain.  But in the end, I did it anyway and it works. It is the safest route. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I believe, however, that if your site loads without a subdomain (i.e., no www), the cookie would be set globally, for all subdomains. I'm not sure of your end setup, so I agree that the safest route is best.